# expand an array in a specific direction

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement the join5 game (an implementation is available here : https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Morpion_solitaire)

and i have to expand the board in a specific direction if the player reaches a bound.

since i'm working with static arrays ( no malloc etc...) i can't realloc them. Therefore i have to recopy them into bigger ones. 
I'm thinking about making an enum to make me choose the direction. And then recopy the elements according to the direction I.E adding a row or columns of zeroes before the first row or after the last row. what i managed to do was to expand the matrix in all directions which means a 2x2 matrix becomes a 4x4 etc...
but i'd like to be able to pass the direction as an argument and add a row, column etc...

here's the code that expand the matrix in all directions.
Tplateau is a structure that have a height, a length and a 2d array.

My question is : how could i make the array expand in a specified direction ?

Thank you by advance for your help !

````
Tplateau * expandMatrixBy(Tplateau *jeu, int number) {

    Tplateau *jeu2;
    int i,j;
    jeu2->hauteur = jeu->hauteur+number;
    jeu2->longueur = jeu->longueur+number;

  for (int row = number; row < jeu2->hauteur; row++) {
    for (int col = number; col < jeu2->longueur; col++) {
      jeu2->plat[row][col] = jeu2->plat[row - number][col - number];
    }
  }
  return jeu2;
}```
````

Comment: 1. You didn't ask a question. 2. A linked list might be a better data structure. You can easily insert or append at the head or tail.

Comment: You don't need to expand in any particular direction, *per se*.  The only real difference is where you put the original data in the new array. Anything else is just bookkeeping, such as mapping logical indices to real indices (if you make such a distinction).

Comment: Array in C is by definition is of fixed size. You can not expand it. All you can do is allocate new array and copy.

Comment: Well, reading that wiki page, it looks like the last record was 178 moves (Rosin in 2011). So, why don't you just declare a big array, let's say 512x512, put the cross in the middle and avoid copying and reshaping at all? Just keep track of the moves and of the extremes reached.

Comment: It does indeed make most sense to malloc an array with max size to cover the worst case, then decide how much of it to use/display.